# What is "remedy against the lusts of the flesh"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, ambiguity

I am struggling to understand the following sentence.

> “I tell them that if they will occupy themselves with the study of mathematics they will find in it the best remedy against the lusts of the flesh.”
>
> ― Thomas Mann

I read [this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/353274/what-are-desires-of-the-flesh/353276?newreg=77fd8386f948472982be4741ea2290c7) but still I don't understand "... remedy against ... ".

Does the phrase "the best remedy against the lusts of the flesh" mean the best remedy *after* 'damages' of sexual activities, etc. or does it mean the best means to *prevent* someone from the lusts of the flesh, or something else?

Comment: I don't have time to write a proper answer now, but roughly: "this is the best way to quench sexual desires".

Comment: What exactly are *'damages' of sexual activities"*?

Comment: If only I had known, at 13, that hard study of mathematics would distract me from impure thoughts!

Comment: Could you give the source of this quotation please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[Lust](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lust)*** is not a sexual activity. Lust is a **desire** for sexual activity (among other things):

> 1 Strong sexual desire.
>   *‘he knew that his lust for her had returned’*
>
> > 1.1 [in singular] A passionate desire for something.
> >     *‘a lust for power’*
> >
> > 1.2 [usually **lusts**] *Theology* A sensuous appetite regarded as sinful.
> >     *‘lusts of the flesh’*

Therefore, a *remedy against lust* cures the lust, the desire itself. The person so cured will have no desire for activities that bring (only) bodily pleasure.

(In other words, he's saying that studying math will keep them from masturbating and/or fornicating - whichever they were doing.)

Answer (score -1):

> Does the phrase "the best remedy against the lusts of the flesh" mean
>   the best remedy **after** 'damages' of sexual activities, etc. or does
>   it mean the best means to **prevent** someone from the lusts of the
>   flesh?

With **remedy** meaning:  [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/remedy)

> something that relieves or cures a problem or illness

My sense, by rewriting the phrase for explanation, would be:

“I tell them that if they will occupy themselves with the study of mathematics, they will find in it the best remedy against the lusts of the flesh, *now and in the future*”

Comment: Wow. Such a simple question, yet you have somehow managed to completely avoid answering it.